# Failed building JavaScript bundle. node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Transformer.transform is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to create a React-Native app using Expo (sdk version 41) but when running the app on a physical device (expo start --android) i stumble upon this error which tells me that

> Transformer.transform is not a function

here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

here's a my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config": "^3.3.41",
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.1.61",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.12.1",
    "deep-equal": "^2.0.5",
    "expo": "^41.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~11.0.2",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~9.1.2",
    "expo-sqlite": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "metro": "^0.66.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.2.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```